# Why is config.proxy ignored when making an axios request within a webpack project?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, proxy, axios

### My goal

I want to perform a request with [axios@0.18.0](https://github.com/axios) using an http proxy fully efficient (squid). My project is a vue project based on the *webpack* template. `vue init webpack proxytest`

### The issue

When I try to perform the request, axios 'ignores' the **proxy** property inside the config object passed.

I noticed that when I run the *exact same* code with pure nodejs, everything works just perfectly fine.

Is there some configuration that I need to specify excepting the axios request configuration when using axios as a npm module within webpack ?

### The code

```
import axios from 'axios';

const config = {
  proxy: {
    host: 'host',
    port: 3128,
  },
  method: 'GET',
};

axios('http://www.bbc.com/', config).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Of course, when testing, I change *'host'* into the proxy IP.

---

I tried to change the **method** property to *POST* in order to check if axios considered the config. It does consider the config passed. 
I tried to put a fake port so I could check if the proxy property was considered. It's not considered.

### The output

[output...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skw6J.png)

Now, I'm aware of what CORS is. The point is I'm constently getting this output when performing the requests. And if the proxy was used by axios, I think no CORS "error" would show up as my proxy is a VPS.

Thank you.

Comment: the problem is cors, and who controls cors is the server. This has nothing to do with vpn nor webpack.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your server to receive the requests and then test. This does not seem to have anything to do with the webpack, because in your mistake, for example, you make a request for the BBC from localhost and it is very likely that you are making that mistake. So it's important to test with your server by running Front and Back locally.